# DomParser parseFromString removing nodes

Tags: javascript, templates, html-parsing, domparser

I came across some strange behaviour when using the DomParser. It appears that if the first element is a TEMPLATE, it's ignored.

See the output of below:

```js
printTags('<template></template><h1></h1>', 'text/html');
document.write('<hr>')
printTags('<h1></h1><template></template>', 'text/html');

function printTags(str)
{
 let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
 document.write(Array.from(doc.body.children).map(child => child.tagName).join(','));
}
```

Browser: Chrome 72

Is this usual behaviour? If so, where can I find the documentation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: @Geuis Can you specify which part of that explains the behavior here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMParser()` parse HTML source code from the string into a DOM. It's not sure that string contents parsed as `body`, so try wrapping it with `<body>` tag.

```js
printTags('<body><template></template><h1></h1></body>', 'text/html');
document.write('<hr>')
printTags('<body><h1></h1><template></template></body>', 'text/html');

function printTags(str) {
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  document.write(Array.from(doc.body.children).map(child => child.tagName).join(','));
}
```

Comment: It's a nice solution and it works, but it doesn't explain why starting with a `<h1>` tag is treated differently than if you start with a `<template>` tag.

Comment: Its not about starting tag.. you are using `doc.body.children` in map which is `<body>` but `DOMParser()` added the `<template>`  to the `<head>` because `<template>` has  `<head>` 
as permitted parents. if still not clear print the `doc` variable in console and had a look at it. Thank You

Comment: I think I understand. When the parser reaches the `<template>` tag as the first node the insertion mode is set to "in head" because it doesn't have any context other than that `<head>` is a permitted parent. When the parser reaches `<h1>` is the insertion mode is set to "in body" as headers aren't permitted in the head of a document which is why the template in the second example is added to the body of the document.

Comment: @GlennKnight Great. That's it