# Is DOMParser().parseFromString() worth using?

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#DOMParser_HTML_extension

It looks like the DOMParser uses innerHTML to add stringified elements to the DOM.  What's the advantage of using it?

I have compared the difference between using DOMParser().parseFromString() and using element.innerHTML below.  Am I overlooking something?

**Using DOMParser**

```
const main = document.querySelector('main');


const newNodeString = '<body><h2>I made it on the page</h2><p>What should I do now?</p><select name="whichAdventure"><option>Chill for a sec.</option><option>Explore all that this page has to offer...</option><option>Run while you still can!</option></select><p>Thanks for your advice!</p></body>';

// Works as expected
let newNode = new DOMParser().parseFromString(newNodeString, 'text/html');
let div = document.createElement('div');

console.log('%cArray.from: ', 'border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;font-weight:1000;');
Array.from(newNode.body.children).forEach((node, index, array) => {
    div.appendChild(node);
    console.log('length:', array.length, 'index: ', index, 'node: ', node);    
})
main.appendChild(div);
```

**Using innerHTML**

```
const main = document.querySelector('main');


const newNodeString = '<h2>I made it on the page</h2><p>What should I do now?</p><select name="whichAdventure"><option>Chill for a sec.</option><option>Explore all that this page has to offer...</option><option>Run while you still can!</option></select><p>Thanks for your advice!</p>';

// Works as expected
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = newNodeString;

main.appendChild(div);
```

I expect that DOMParser().parseFromString() provides some additional functionality that I'm unaware of.

Comment: It helps you avoid invalid HTML by putting a `<body>` inside a `<div>`, but if that’s all the manipulation you need to do then maybe it isn’t worth it. Invalid HTML is a fact of life.

Comment: that link is to a super-old patch for browsers that are dead. DOMParser gives you a document object. It gives you slightly more control with whole docs (incl head) than an offline node. You might not need that control for simple applications, and can live with the quirks (such as TR tags and whatnot)

Comment: @Ry- that's an error created when trying to use a solution found in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136078/8916612.  I've updated it.  Also, the browser appears to strip out body tags that are embedded in the body, so that caused no issue in parsing the html.

Comment: Right, it strips out invalid HTML through error correction, which is why it isn’t a big deal. Anyway, if all you’re doing is setting `innerHTML` and inserting that into the document, there’s no point in parsing with `DOMParser` first. If you’re *not* inserting directly into the document, then its value shows up – for example, when sanitizing potentially malicious HTML. The simple act of setting `innerHTML` can run scripts (`<img onerror>` IIRC).

Comment: @Ry- that does not add value either as setting any elements to the DOM can run scripts.

Comment: consider `document.createElement('div').innerHTML= '<img onerror=alert(666) src=/4>'; `; you don't get that alert() with a DOMParser(), which also doesn't hit the url endpoint like innerHTML example would.  Note that's _without_ attaching to the document.

Comment: @dandavis there won't be an alert in either situation until you actually attach it to the DOM.

```document.createElement``` creates an element in memory just like ```DOMParser()```

Comment: The link you've shared does not give the code the browser uses to implement `DOMParser`; it is more of a polyfill. I wouldn't assume anything about browser internals from that code.

Comment: @participator: I said “if you’re not inserting directly into the document”. And “there won't be an alert in either situation until you actually attach it to the DOM” is incorrect – try it.

Comment: @Ry- and dandavis you two are right.  Weird. That's not what I was expecting at all.

Comment: There's a few other miscellaneous side effects too. iirc, problem included; imported stylesheets, external media, `<base>` tags, `<title>` tags, namespace pollution, and minor/possibly outmoded quirks, including all of IE's innerHTML madness from over the years. For simple examples, innerHTML works and does so intuitively and cleanly. When innerHTML _doesn't_ work for a project for one reason or another, you _can_ use the more precise and verbose tools; DOMParser is a nice ace to tuck up your sleeve...

Comment: @dandavis any chance you know where these quirks are documented?

Comment: I do not, and most of those problems with innerHTML are probably outmoded by now (`text/html` support was a long time ago). You might look into the advantages of document fragments as those will share similar properties. The remaining big innerHTML issues (afaik) are `<img>`,`<audio>`,`<video>,` reaching out to a _src_ attribute, and the attrib-based XSS shown above.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one thing, `DOMParser` can [parse XML files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_XML). It also validates that the XML is well formed and produces meaningful errors if not. More to the point, it is using the right tool for the right job.

I've used it in the past to take an uploaded XML file and produce HTML using a predefined XSLT style sheet, without getting a server involved.

Obviously, if all you're doing is appending the string to an existing DOM, and `innerHTML` (or `outerHTML`) works for you, continue using it.

Comment: aren't the only xml tags that an html parser would have trouble on <title>, <head>, and <body>?

Comment: Depends on the parser, of course. IE parsers tends to go nuts. The parser would happily accept the XML, sure, but to what end? Unless you have CSS applied to the elements, it would be silly to use `innerHTML` to parse and manipulate XML.

Comment: @HereticMonkey good point, however, I am interested in parsing html.

Comment: @participator I am answering the question in the title, "Is DOMParser().parseFromString() worth using?"